# asp.net Modify list from FindAll or Where without modifying original list searched

Tags: asp.net, linq, list, where-clause, findall

I'm trying to create a new list from findall or where and modify that new list without it making changes to the original.  When creating list2 from FindAll and a change is made to list2, it should not affect list1.  How come?

Edit... Used combination of both answers which seems to be working. Any foreseen issues???  Working code edited
Edit... It's not working.  A class that is a property of the object does not have its data copied...  Any ideas??? I can't see why just copy or clone isn't plain and simple for a list.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started");
        List<SampleData> list1 = SampleData.MakeList(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("list1.Number => " + list1[i].Number);
            Console.WriteLine("list1.Person => " + list1[i].Person);
        }
        List<SampleData> list2 = new List<SampleData>(list1.FindAll(m => m.Number == 1).Select(x => new SampleData().ShallowCopy())).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; i++)
        {
            list2[i].Person = "Person " + list2[i].Number;
            Console.WriteLine("list2.Number => " + list2[i].Number);
            Console.WriteLine("list2.Person => " + list2[i].Person);
        }

        SampleData sd = list2.Find(s => s.Number == 1);
        Console.WriteLine("Apartment Number" + sd.apartment.BuildingLetter); // <<<<------------------- THROWING NULL EXCEPTION FOR APARTMENT

        Console.WriteLine("-------AFTER MODIFYING NEW LIST----LIST1.Person SHOULD BE NULL---");
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--list1.Number => " + list1[i].Number);
            Console.WriteLine("--list1.Person => " + list1[i].Person);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--list2.Number => " + list2[i].Number);
            Console.WriteLine("--list2.Person => " + list2[i].Person);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }

}
class SampleData
{      
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public String Person { get; set; }
    public Apartment apartment { get; set; }
    public static List<SampleData> MakeList(int count)
    {
        List<SampleData> l = new List<SampleData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            SampleData d = new SampleData();
            d.apartment = new Apartment { RoomNumber = i, BuildingLetter = "letter-" + i };
            d.Number = i;
            l.Add(d);
        }
        return l;
    }
    public SampleData ShallowCopy()
    {
        return (SampleData)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

}
class Apartment
{
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
    public String BuildingLetter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Apparently that does not work when there is an addition class as one of the properties.  A property that is a separate class does not have its data copied.  See edited code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **. AsNoTracking()** Method in  case **Entity Query** wheen select from  **DbContext** or **ObjectContext**

```
List<SampleData> list2 = new List<SampleData>(list1.Where(m => m.Number == 1).AsNoTracking().ToList());
```

---

or use a Copy Contractor like that

```
class SampleData
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public String Person { get; set; }

    public SampleData(SampleData obj)
    {
        This.Number=obj.Number;
        This.Person=obj.Person;
        ..
        ..
    }
    public static List<SampleData> MakeList(int count)
    {
        List<SampleData> l = new List<SampleData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            SampleData d = new SampleData();
            d.Number = i;
            l.Add(d);
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

Then

```
 List<SampleData> list2 = new List<SampleData>(list1.Where(m => m.Number == 1).Select(x=>new SampleData(x)).ToList());
```

Comment: This list of the SampleData class is a very small class of properties.  This is easy enough for a small class but for a large class, there's a lot more properties.  Is there an easier way to get all the properties without specifying each one in the select.  So all the properties of that item are copied over?

Answer (score 0):

ShallowCopy is your friend.

Define a ShallowCopy() method within your SampleData class like this.

```
class SampleData
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public String Person { get; set; }
    public static List<SampleData> MakeList(int count)
    {
        List<SampleData> l = new List<SampleData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            SampleData d = new SampleData();
            d.Number = i;
            l.Add(d);
        }
        return l;
    }

    public SampleData ShallowCopy()
    {
        return (SampleData)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

}
```

Then populate list2 as follows...

```
List<SampleData> list2 = new List<SampleData>();
foreach (SampleData sd in list1.Where(m => m.Number == 1))
{
    list2.Add(sd.ShallowCopy());
}
```

Comment: So I used a combination of both answers from shady and gthb7.  Thank you for both inputs.  I couldn't get AsNoTracking method to be recognized (tried adding references for System.Data.Entity and EntityFramework but didn't show up... which looked much easier and cleaner.  So used a combination of the 2.  I didn't want to be responsible for added and remember to add all the properties so the ShallowCopy was a good addtion to the first which seems to work.  Any foreseen issues???? code used that has it working I'm going to edit my original post

Comment: *Any foreseen issues?* Maybe. Note that `MemberwiseClone` does create a shallow copy, but if it contains collections, the items in the collections are *not* copied (it's a new collection with the same items).